# iOS - Placing two label together in centre of their super view

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have two label, L1 and L2 of variable and nonidentical length. I want to place these two label using constraints in Xcode. If possible i don't want to manipulate constraints programmatically. guidance will be appreciated.

[image: Right image should be the expected output]

Right image should be the expected output

Requirements,

1. Two labels are non identical in width
2. When running leading space of L1 and trailing space of L2 will be equal
3. distance between L1 & L2, horizontal space is fixed, 10 px
4. **UIStackView cannot be used**

How can I do it from Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is put both the `UILabel` inside a `UIView` and then:

- Add a leading, top and bottom to the *superView* to your *HEL* `UILabel`.
- Add a trailing, top and bottom to the *superView* to your *HEAVENLY* `UILabel`.
- Add a horizontal spacing of 10 points between your two `UILabel`

Now center your `UIView` horizontally and vertically in the middle of the screen. Set the horizontally in center constraint priority to 250. Add a leading and trailing space of your `UIView` to its *superView* with a `>=` 5 constraint

**Edit:** Additionally if the text is too large then the above constraints aren't simply enough to work perfectly (You will have to set the *numberOfLines* to 0 and *wrap mode* to *wordWrap* to display the complete text and go to the next line, of course)! As the `UILabel`s will have their *inferred height* and *inferred width* with a priority of 750 and the content compression resistance priority of each `UILabel` is 750 by default too, Xcode will be confused what to do and rightfully so! What you can do is set the *content compression* property in *attributes inspector* to 1000

[image]

**OR**

If you don't wish to tinker with *compression resistance* (I used to find them scary), what you can also do is add a `>=` constraint to the width and height both of each `UILabel`. Giving this constraint will also work to show the complete text no matter how large it be, as explicitly defining height and width has given them a priority of 1000!

Comment: Give the same baseline so that they can keep their horizontal alignment same.

Comment: `UIView`s height will be unknown right? How does Xcode  handle it?

Comment: `UIView` height and width will be inferred from its content. In this case the two `UILabel`

Answer (score -1):

is your L1 and L2's width is fixed value or  uncertain value  ?

if the width is fixed， you can used Masonry to realization effect。

Comment: Those are uncertain. Thats why the problem arose.